# extracting the value of a tag from xml in which xml message is coming as string

Tags: java, xml

I have the below method  ...

```
public void sendmessage( final String messageText) 
{
}
```

and  in which the parameter messageText contains a an xml message now out of this xml message i need to extract the value of an xml tag and sent it it into an integer variable

that is in the above string parameter messageText which contains an xml message there is this tag as shown below

```
<transferGroupId>206320940</transferGroupId>
```

now i want to extract the e value of this tag and strored inside a variable please advise how to achieve this

below is the complete xml message shown below..

```
<?l version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <emml message="emml-transfer-lifecycle">
        <messageHeader>
            <businessDate>2016-01-09</businessDate>
            <eventDateTime timeContextReference="London">2016-01-09T16:55:00.485
            </eventDateTime>
            <system id="ACSDE">
                <systemId>ADS ABLO</systemId>
                <systemClass>ADS</systemClass>
                <systemRole>Reference</systemRole>
            </system>
            <timeContext id="ndon">
                <location>ABLO</location>
            </timeContext>
        </messageHeader>
        <transferEventHeader>
            <transferGroupStatus>Settled</transferGroupStatus>
            <transferGroupIdentifier>
                <transferGroupId>206320940</transferGroupId>
                <systemReference>Ghtr</systemReference>
                <transferGroupClassificationScheme>Primary Identifier
                </transferGroupClassificationScheme>
            </transferGroupIdentifier>
        </transferEventHeader>
    </emml>
```

I have tried this approach as shown below

```
String tagname = "transferGroupId";
        String t = getTagValue( messageText,  tagname);
```

and then further it is calling this method ..

```
public static String getTagValue(String messageText, String tagname){
    return messageText.split("<"+tagname+">")[1].split("</"+tagname+">")[0];
```

but it this does not work in the end please advise how can i overcome from this

the other thing that was advise of jsoup also i have tried as shown below but it is throwing the exception that Parser class does not have any method named xmlParser in it ..

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(messageText, "", Parser.xmlParser());
            for (Element e : doc.select("transferGroupId")) {
                System.out.println(e.text());
            }
```

Comment: what's the "e value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JSoup** sounds like what you need. (It has xml parsing support)

In JSoup:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(messageText, "", Parser.xmlParser());
for (Element e : doc.select("transferGroupId")) {
    System.out.println(e.text());
}
```

This will print out the text of the transferGroupId, which is `206320940` in this case. You can do other things with this such as sending a message using your own methods and resources.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Programmer but i am getting an compilation error on this statement Parser.xmlParser() , as it is saying that Parser class does not have any method named xmlparser in it , Please advise how to overcome from this

Comment: @saralsaxena glad you found the answer! is it working now?